# In how many ways we can place $N$ mutually non-attacking knights on an $M \times M$ chessboard?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

Given $N,M$ with $1 \le M \le 6$ and $1\le N \le 36$. In how many ways we can place $N$ knights (mutually non-attacking) on an $M \times M$ chessboard?

For example:

$M = 2, N = 2$, ans $= 6$
$M = 3, N = 2$, ans $ = 28$
$M = 6, N = 15$, ans $= 2560$

It is possible to solve this using graph theory. However, I am (more) interested in a combinatorial approach (A closed form solution).

[Similar problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnightsProblem.html)

Comment: Do you mean that they are to be mutually non-attacking?

Comment: Clearly the answer is $M^2$ choose $N$. What does graph theory have to do with it?

Comment: @Chris Eagle: I don't think that $\choose{{M^2},{N}}$ is giving the right answer.

Comment: Ummm, you do realize graph theory is combinatorial, don't you?

Comment: @user62427 I think Chris was answering the question before the "non-attacking" condition was added.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that there is a closed formula. It seems more likely that there is an asymptotic formula as $M$ gets large.

Comment: @Gregg There is clearly such an algorithm - just count them. That's not what we call a "closed form," usually, although "closed form" often is not a rigorously defined term.

Comment: I don't see how it is "easy" to write it as a summation as you describe. In general, obvious, if $S$ is a set, then $|S|=\sum_{s\in S} 1$. But that's not usually what we'd call a closed form for $|S|$, either. Certainly, the notion of "closed form" is flexible, depending on the problem, but there are some answers which just are obviously not "closed form" in any useful sense. @Gugg

Answer (score 3):

The complete answer to this question is contained in the Knights
polynomials.  By definition, the coefficient of $q^k$ in the $m\times n$
knights polynomial, $K_{m,n}(q)$, is the number
of ways that $k$ non-attacking knights can be placed on an $m\times n$
board. Of course, it's a tautology to say that this solves the problem,
but there is an algorithm to compute them. Using this algorithm, the
first six $m\times n$ knights polynomials (per your request) are

\begin{align}
K_{1,1}(q) &= q+1 \\
K_{2,2}(q) &= q^4+4 q^3+6 q^2+4 q+1 \\
K_{3,3}(q) &= 2 q^5+18 q^4+36 q^3+28 q^2+9 q+1\\
K_{4,4}(q) &= 6 q^8+48 q^7+170 q^6+340 q^5+412 q^4+276 q^3+96 q^2+16 q+1\\
K_{5,5}(q) &= q^{13}+15 q^{12}+158 q^{11}+994 q^{10}+3679 q^9+8526 q^8+12996
q^7+13384 q^6 \\
&+ \; 9386 q^5+4436 q^4+1360 q^3+252 q^2+25 q+1\\
K_{6,6}(q) &= 2 q^{18}+40 q^{17}+393 q^{16}+2560 q^{15}+12488 q^{14}+47684
q^{13}+141969 q^{12} \\
&+ \; 323476 q^{11}+556274 q^{10}+716804 q^9+688946
q^8+491140 q^7+257318 q^6 \\
&+ \; 97580 q^5+26133 q^4+4752 q^3+550 q^2+36 q+1
\end{align}

Note that these polynomials agree with the results that you provide.  For example, the coefficient of $q^{15}$ in $K_{6,6}$ is 2560, corresponding to your statement that $M=6,N=15 \Rightarrow \text{ans} =2560$.  The coefficients of $q^2$ also agree with [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/search?q=nonattacking%20knights&sort=&language=&go=Search).

The algorithm to compute these is very similar to the obviously related Kings
problem.  Neil Calkin and his REU students provide a very thorough analysis
of that problem in two papers in Congressus Numerantium.  Shaina Race has a 
publicly accessible presentation of their results [here](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~slrace/gsskings.pdf). I published a [paper](https://f521ffe9-a-b04e5bb8-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/unca.edu/mark-mcclure/home/scholarship/KingsProblem.pdf) presenting
an implementation of the algorithm in Mathematica V5.  The technique for counting 
knights is a bit more complicated but uses very similar ideas.  Unfortunately,
I've been able to compute the $7\times 7$ knights polynomial but my computer
chokes on $8\times 8$, the size of an actual chess board.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, see [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=nonattacking%20knights&sort=&language=&go=Search) for a list of numbers. E.g. Sequence [A172132](http://oeis.org/A172132) counts the number of ways to place 2 nonattacking knights on an $n\times n$ board. Note this site should be among the first ones (besides Google) which you should visit when you have a combinatorial problem (like counting).

Secondly, I don't have a "closed formula" for this problem, but an algorithm which should work for the given input limits. Since the problem is of quite an [ACM/ICPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACM_International_Collegiate_Programming_Contest) nature, I would assume you'd be satisfied with an algorithm which (when implemented correctly) would give the answer in reasonable time.

---

My algorithm is dynamic programming (Some prefer "recursion" because no optimization is involved. I don't distinguish them here.).

Let $f[i,j,v_{last},v_{second\_last}]$ denote the number of ways to place $j$ non-attacking knights in the first $i$ rows of the $n\times n$ board with the last and the second last rows having the states denoted by $v_{last}$ and $v_{second\_last}$. Those are two bit-vectors, with 1 being a knight. So a row with two knights in the 2nd and 5th cell when $n=5$ will be denoted as 01001.

So the most important part would be the equation (state transition equation)
$$
f[i,j,v_{last},v_{second\_last}] = \sum_{v_{third\_last}}f[i-1,j-\operatorname{popcount}(v_{last}),v_{second\_last},v_{third\_last}]
$$ where $\operatorname{popcount}(v)$ is the number of 1's in bit-vector $v$.
Note the three vectors must be consistent (non-attacking).

There're then $N M 2^{2M}$ states, and the transition takes another $2^M$ time, so the algorithm (if implemented properly) has a time complexity of $O(N M 2^{3M})$. The bound is not tight, since there're many invalid combinations of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

See http://oeis.org/A244081 and the crossreferences or my book http://problem64.beda.cz/silo/kotesovec_non_attacking_chess_pieces_2013_6ed.pdf, page 283-285.