# How many ways are there to tile a chessboard with 32 knights?

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

The maximal amount of knights which can be places on a regular $8 \times 8$ chessboard so that no two take each other is $32$ (To see this just notice that a knight on a black square only attacks knights placed on white squares).

I was wondering how many ways there are to tile a regular chessboard with these $32$ knights so that no two take each other.

A generalisation of this question has already been posed here: [In how many ways we can place $N$ mutually non-attacking knights on an $M \times M$ chessboard?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304871/in-how-many-ways-we-can-place-n-mutually-non-attacking-knights-on-an-m-times). However, the answers given include a polynomial approach which cannot be used in the case of an $8 \times 8$ chessboard, because, as an answer states, a computer struggles to compute such a polynomial.

Even if it were quite easy for a computer to compute such a polynomial, in an Olympiad no such computational power is allowed. Hence, I was wondering if there was a pure combinatorics approach for this particular case.

An example of such a tiling is to place all the knights on all the black cells.

Comment: You can put the knights on the black squares or on the white squares. This makes two ways. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ajotatxe Are there no other possibilities? Can you prove this?

Comment: Actually, you can place 64 knights on the chessboard, one on each square. Perhaps you left out some condition?

Comment: @bof Hahaha, yes that's true. I have edited my answer now.

Comment: Consider a [knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) of the chessboard. Obviously, if $32$ of the $64$ squares are occupied by non-attacking knights, then the tour must alternate between occupied and unoccupied squares. This means that there are (at most) two ways to place the $32$ knights. But of course there are two ways, use all the black squares or all the white squares.

Comment: In graph-theoretic terms: A cycle graph $C_{2n}$ has exactly two independent sets of size $n.$ Therefore, a Hamiltonian graph of order $2n$ has at most two independent sets of size $n.$ The knight's graph on the $8\times8$ chessboard is a Hamiltonian graph of order $64.$

Comment: @bof: I think your comments could be combined as a (very nice) answer.

Comment: @bof To clarify the knight's tour argument a little, note that the knight's tour visits alternating black and white squares. (This might seem too obvious to mention, but I did have to pause a moment to recall it.)

Comment: The existence of a knight's tour seems crucial here. Actually, in a $2\times 2$ board there is no knight's tour, and there are $6$ ways to put two non-attacking horses on it.

Comment: @quasi Thank you, but it's way past my bedtime, so I don't feel like composing a formal answer. Feel free to write the answer yourself, no acknowledgment is necessary.

Comment: @bof: No, it's yours -- it can wait.

Comment: When I said "knight's tour" I meant a closed (re-entrant) knight's tour.

Comment: @bof I have written up your solutions and credited them to you

Answer (score 2):

This is [bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof)'s solution to the problem.

Consider a [knight's tour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour) of the chessboard. Obviously, if $32$ of the $64$ squares are occupied by non-attacking knights, then the tour must alternate between occupied and unoccupied squares, since a horse can only attack a square if the opposite colour. This means that there are (at most) two ways to place the $32$ knights. We can offer examples of these two ways: use all the black squares or all the white squares.

Another way to look at the problem is to consider graph theory. A cycle graph $C_{2n}$ has exactly two independent sets of size $n$. Therefore, a Hamiltonian graph of order $2n$ has at most two independent sets of size $n$. The knight's graph on the $8 \times 8$ chessboard is a Hamiltonian graph of order 64. From here we can conclude in the same manner as in the first solution.